# Recover failed raster calculator operation QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster-calculator

Users can recover their raster calculator algorithms via the "results" panel in ArcMap (i.e., analogous to viewing one's "history"). Is there a similar function in QGIS?

In other words, is there a way to recover raster calculator equations after they have already been (unsuccessfully) run?